# Sacar el primer carácter no repetido en una frase

Tags: java, string

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio donde necesito sacar el primer carácter no duplicado de una frase que me pide por pantalla con java, hasta ahora tengo esto el problema es que me saca el último carácter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Escriba una frase");
    String cadena = lector.next();
    int contador = 1;
    char caracter = 0;

    while (cadena.length() != 0) { 
        int contadorAux = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < cadena.length(); j++) {
            if (cadena.charAt(0) == cadena.charAt(j)) {
                contadorAux++;
            }
        }

        if (contadorAux == contador) { 
            contador = contadorAux;
            caracter = cadena.charAt(0);
        }

        cadena = cadena.replaceAll(cadena.charAt(0) + "" , "");
    }

    System.out.println(caracter);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por estar pendiente y editar tu pregunta. Sin embargo, en la edición se te pasó validar que dejaras claro Cuál es tu pregunta. :)

Answer (score 2):

La instrucción `lector.next()` te va a extraer solamente la primera palabra de la frase. Debes usar `lector.nextLine()`.

Estás fijando las comparaciones al primer caracter cuando haces esto: `cadena.charAt(0)`.

---

Te propongo lo siguiente:

- Primero extrae toda la frase con `lector.nextLine()`.
- Con un ciclo `for` recorres toda la frase caracter por caracter.
- Dentro del ciclo `for` recorres con otro ciclo `for` toda la frase
  caracter por caracter.

De esta manera el ciclo `for` externo fija el caracter que quieres evaluar y el ciclo `for` interno se mueve por la frase buscando repeticiones.

Tan pronto se encuentre que el caracter en evaluación se repite sales del ciclo `for` interno para evaluar el siguiente caracter.

Si el ciclo `for` interno llega al final de la frase y no se encontró una repetición entonces el caracter que estaba siendo evaluado es el primero sin repeticiones, por lo tanto sales de los dos ciclos y muestras en pantalla el resultado:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Escriba una frase");
    String cadena = lector.nextLine();

    char caracter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {

        boolean repetido = false;
        for(int j = 0; !repetido && j < cadena.length(); j++) {
            if(j != i)
                repetido = cadena.charAt(i) == cadena.charAt(j);
        }

        if(!repetido) {
            caracter = cadena.charAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(caracter);
}
```